# Prove that the Composite of Surjection is Surjection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this proof okay?

---

Let $f:B\rightarrow C$ and $g:A\rightarrow B$ be onto, then by definition:
\begin{align*}
&\forall c \in C, \exists b\in B,\text{ s.t. } f(b)=c \ \ \ \text{ and}\\
&\forall b \in B, \exists a\in A,\text{ s.t. } g(a)=b 
\end{align*}
By definition of composition (from Hubbard p.15):
\begin{align*}
(f\circ g)(a)=f[g(a)]
\end{align*}
with domain $A$ and codomain $C$.

Then $f[g(a)]=f(b)=c$.

---

I am asking because I saw an alternative proof that mentions the axiom of choice to choose one value from a or b if there are multiple values. This confuses the hell out of me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that that was what they proved? Usually the Axiom of Choice comes up when showing that every surjection has a right inverse, like so: http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/41517.pdf

Comment: Do you think it's possible to use it if you prove it backward?

Comment: Prove what backwards?

Comment: Start with c and prove its right inverse is b

Comment: Are $c$ and $b$ functions? From where to where? Could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: I will put up that proof later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of $g$ is the entirety of $B$ by hypothesis. Since $f $ is surjective, there is always some element in $B $ (the image of $f $!) So that $f (b)=c $ for all $c \in C $. Surely, there is also an $a \in A $ so that $g (a)=b $.

I'm not a "choice expert" but it seems like a technicality. For example, if $A=\mathbb R$, $B=\{a\} $, and $C=\{s\}$. then $g $ is the constant map, but you need to pick some real number, even if they all "work." However,  since we are only asserting the existence of such elements, choice is not required.

Comment: Can you also comment on how axiom of choice could be use?

Comment: Sure, I added some detail and also commented on a little bit of why choice might have shown up

Comment: We don't need choice, because we don't need to pick an element $a$ such that $gf(a) = c$; we just need to assert the *existence* of an element.